# open all documents in a folder and make them in a list

Tags: python, file, document

I want to open all documents in a folder and make every document into an element of a list like: `["doc1", "doc2", "doc3", ... ]`

```
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('filepath'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*-*'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as text:
            lines=text.readlines()
print lines
```

However, it just makes all contents of the documents into a string.

Please tell me how to reach the expected result.

Comment: What do you want in the list? The *contents* of the file or the *name*?

Comment: What do you mean by "open" which does not match what the code does?  Your terminology sounds like maybe you want to open OpenOffice on documents which are OpenOffice documents, an image viewer on images, etc; is this what you actually want?  Programmers like to talk about "directories" (not "folders"), and "open" definitely means "open for reading" (or writing) into e.g. a string.  Or do you simply want to collect the matching filenames into a list of filenames?  Please update your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Did you try os.listdir? https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 2):

```
docs = []
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('filepath'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*-*'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as text:
            docs.append(text.read())
print docs
```

Answer (score 0):

A general glass to get different paths of file types from a folder

```
idir = "c:\\data\\"  #In directory

class Paths_to_files:
    def __init__(self, idir):
        self.idir = idir
    def get_paths(self, rf):
        rf_list = []
        listing = os.listdir(self.idir) 
        for files in listing:
            if rf in files:
                rf_list.append(files)
        return sorted(rf_list)

class Wrapper(Paths_to_files):      
    def __init__(self, idir):
        self.idir = idir

#Get all files:
files = Wrapper(idir)

#Get all tiff files:
tifpath = files.get_paths('tif')

#Get all csv files:
csvpath = files.get_paths('csv')
```